# SQL multiple INSERT OR UPDATE

Tags: sql, sql-server, insert-update

I was saving a set of values (1 record) to a table in this way:

```
UPDATE Table SET ...
IF @@ROWCOUNT = 0 INSERT INTO Table ...
```

This worked fine, but now I need to add more independent records at the same time, so I tried something like:

```
UPDATE Table SET ...
IF @@ROWCOUNT = 0 INSERT INTO Table ...

UPDATE Table SET ...
IF @@ROWCOUNT < 2 INSERT INTO Table ...

UPDATE Table SET ...
IF @@ROWCOUNT < 3 INSERT INTO Table ...

UPDATE Table SET ...
IF @@ROWCOUNT < 4 INSERT INTO Table ...
```

...in order to keep it in 1 transaction. However, starting from the 2nd declaration it adds rows even if the particular row is already existing - apparently `@@ROWCOUNT` does not count `INSERT`ed rows, or I misunderstood its concept another way...

I wonder if there is some feasible way to resolve this within SQL query. In this particular case, it *should* be OK to assume that all records are dependent on existence of the first, but it is not 100% reliable and I would like to know a better solution, if exists.

**EDIT - solution:**

This may not be possible in all applications (be aware, that particular updates are not checked separately), but in my case it apears to work well and should be also consistent with the data, because the set of updated/inserted data is integral.

```
UPDATE Table SET ...  
UPDATE Table SET ... 
UPDATE Table SET ... 
UPDATE Table SET ... 
IF @@ROWCOUNT = 0 
BEGIN
   INSERT INTO Table ...
   INSERT INTO Table ...
   INSERT INTO Table ...
   INSERT INTO Table ...
END
```

Comment: You should be able to make this into a subquery...something like `insert into table case when row_count = 0 then... when row_count = 1 then... end as stuff from (select count(1) as row_count from table)a;`?

Comment: Oh wait...is `@@ROWCOUNT` the number of rows affected by the first `UPDATE`? My tsql is fairly rusty.

Comment: Hmm, pardon my lack of knowledge, but will a subquery really work (with new data) before the transaction is complete?

Comment: Why not look into MERGE? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510625.aspx Trying to do this row by agonizing row is not a great plan.

Comment: Keep in mind that @@ROWCOUNT returns the number of rows affected by the LAST statement. It does not keep a running total of the number of rows affected across multiple statements.

Comment: @SeanLange: You're right, this is written in TSQL reference manual. I forgot about it and misunderstood that with number of rows within last transaction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```html
UPDATE TABLE .....
IF(condition)
BEGIN
/*
do insert here
*/
END
IF(condition)
BEGIN
/*
do insert here
*/
END
```

Source: [SQL Tutorials](http://sqltutorials.blogspot.co.uk/2007/06/sql-ifelse-statement.html)

Comment: That looks really, really clean and simple. I will test it and mark as an asnswer when tested.

Answer (score 4):

A slightly cleaner solution to you problem may be to use:

```
DECLARE @Reasons TABLE ( Name NVARCHAR(50) PRIMARY KEY, ReasonType NVARCHAR(50))

INSERT INTO @Reasons ( Name, ReasonType ) VALUES  ( N'Review', N'Old Reason' )  

SELECT * FROM @Reasons

MERGE INTO @Reasons AS Target  
USING (VALUES 
('Recommendation','Other'),
('Review', 'Marketing'),
('Internet', 'Promotion')
)  
       AS Source (NewName, NewReasonType)  
ON Target.Name = Source.NewName  
WHEN MATCHED THEN  
UPDATE SET ReasonType = Source.NewReasonType  
WHEN NOT MATCHED BY TARGET THEN  
INSERT (Name, ReasonType) VALUES (NewName, NewReasonType)  ;

SELECT * FROM @Reasons
```

Then you'll get all or nothing, without all of the conditions.  See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510625.aspx  details on the merge statement.

Comment: I don't see an UPDATE statement here...? If data exists, then they have to be updated, only if they don't a new record is created.

Comment: Ah, I missed that part.  I'll post an updated solution.

Comment: This is a much better answer than the accepted answer.

Comment: I agree this seems to be solution covering cases where the lines may have been modified indpendently. In my case the accepted solution works fine with no limitations, but I'm sure this second solution will come handy in future too.